# Convert Java generic to Kotlin Generic

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I have Android Java code and tried to convert to Android Kotlin. I have tried in many ways to convert my code to Kotlin but didn't succeed.

I have code in Java as below,

```
public abstract class BaseVM<N> extends ViewModel {
/*Class Body*/
}
public abstract class BaseActivity<T extends ViewDataBinding, V extends BaseVM>{
/*Class Body*/
}
```

Converted to Kotlin as below,

```
abstract class BaseVM<N> : ViewModel() {
/*Class Body*/
}
abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewDataBinding, V : BaseVM>{ // Here Error is *One Type Argument is expected for class BaseVM<N>*
/*Class Body*/
}
```

But I get the following error
**One Type Argument is expected for class BaseVM**

Thanks in advance for your kinds reply.

Comment: What is **N** in your case of `BaseVM`?

Comment: It's generic type placeholder, it's can be interface or any class. But for my case I'll use Interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you should pass * as One Type Argument. You have to declare your **BaseActivity** like below:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<T : Activity, V : BaseVM<*>>
```